# Create a permission in Django that can be optionally applied to superusers

Tags: django, permissions, superuser

I want to create a permission (or something that achieves the same thing) that can be applied to *all* users optionally, including super users.

I can create a custom permission very easily:

```
ct = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(MyModel)
Permission.objects.create(
        name='optional permission',
        codename='optional_permission,
        content_type=ct)
```

However, this will always return True for superusers `user.has_perm('my_app_label.optional_permission')`

My use-case is:
I'd like to create a queryset manager function that only returns Draft articles for users in Groups that have `optional_permission` applied. I'd like superusers to be exempt from seeing these draft articles if they want.

Comment: The baked in superusers are omnipotent by design. If you want superusers that can be denied certain permissions, you need to create your own user model that hardcodes `is_superuser` to False and create your own admins. Quite honestly, it's better to have superusers use 2 accounts, one for real superuser business and one for content management. Superusers have all permissions because otherwise no one would be able to fix the broken model that no one has access to.

Comment: Agree with this, particularly for managing django models. However I'm only using this permission to filter something in the UI. The advantage of using Django Permissions is I get to bake it in with our existing Groups etc. So I don't think there's a 'risk' associated with not having it.

Comment: I think you're in this gray area of using permissions as "preferences" for which there is no baked in facility. You should decide if you get more of these, whether to roll or use a preferences package. Preferences can be set by owner of account, permissions can not. Preferences have no security impact (but can have privacy impact), permissions do. They are very alike implementation wise, since permissions are basically a specialization of preferences :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try to override [**`has_perm`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.has_perm) by passing an additional keyword argument to the original implementation.

```
class User(AbstractUser):
   ...
   def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None, superuser_exempt=True):
       # Active superusers have optional permissions.
       if superuser_exempt:
           if self.is_active and self.is_superuser:
               return True
       # Otherwise we need to check the backends.
       return _user_has_perm(self, perm, obj)
```

Take a look of `has_perm` source code:

```
class PermissionMixin:
    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        """
        Return True if the user has the specified permission. Query all
        available auth backends, but return immediately if any backend returns
        True. Thus, a user who has permission from a single auth backend is
        assumed to have permission in general. If an object is provided, check
        permissions for that object.
        """
        # Active superusers have all permissions.
        if self.is_active and self.is_superuser:
            return True

        # Otherwise we need to check the backends.
        return _user_has_perm(self, perm, obj)
```

`AbstractUser` inherits `has_perm` method from `PermissionMixin`

```
class AbstractUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    ...
```

Comment: Won't this always return True if `superuser_exempt`? What I want is to return whether the superuser actually has that permission or not.

Also, what is `_user_has_perm` here?
Thanks!

Comment: @MDalt this is the source code of the `has_perm`, in original implementation, there is no argument `superuser_exempt`, the super user is shortcuted to return `True` for every permission check. While adding `superuser_exempt`, you could optionally  call `user.has_perm('xxx', superuser_exempt=False)` to force the superuser go through a series of default permission check, that's what the `_user_has_perm`'s job here

Comment: Unfortunately this still doesn't work: `_user_has_perm(self, perm, obj)` will always return True. I've looked into it, and the underlying `_get_permissions` function returns `Permission.objects.all()` for superusers. The only way I could think to get round that is to override the queryset, but that feels hacky.

Comment: Yeah..., seems that breaks the backend

Answer (score 0):

I had to implement a slightly ugly workaround in the end, so would be interested to know if someone can do better.

I had to add an override boolean for superusers on our User model

```
class User(AbstractUser):
   superuser_view_draft_override = models.BooleanField(
        default=False, help_text='This allows us to toggle the \'see draft\' permission for superusers only')

   @cached_property
   def can_see_draft_content(self):
        # Have to use the boolean override for superusers because they
        # have all permissions turned on by default
        if self.is_superuser:
            return self.superuser_view_draft_override

        # Otherwise use the permission...
        return self.has_perm('my_app_label.optional_permission')
```